# Gmail API watch() not working properly

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am trying to run `watch()` on my inbox and send it to a pub/sub.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me.com/watch?alt=json returned "Invalid topicName does not match projects/western-oarlock/topics/*">
```

The code I am sending is:

```
request = {
  'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
  'topicName': 'projects/flask-app/topics/myTopic'
}

service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

Why is it attempting to contact `western-oarlock` instead of `flask-app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up having to do with the JSON Secrets file. I was authenticating on the wrong project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if access token you are using is the right one.
2. Check if .p12 key you are using is from the same project, or try using a new key.

I had the same problem, in my case the cause was access token I used in `Google Cloud API` `OAuth2` authentication which was generated using wrong service account. Hovewer I've read then somewehere on the Internet that wrong .p12 key also can cause this issue.